# Store Data from different websites in Django Database

Tags: javascript, python, django, tags, pixel

I would like to create a Django project to save tags or pixels fires from different websites in a my database:

For this reason, create the following Django model. This one, include all variables that I want to save

```
class Purchase (models.Model):
account = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
user_cookie = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
session_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
….
```

For collect data from other websites I saw  this method. I don’t know if it’s the base way to collect this data.

```
<script>
var e= document.createElement("script");
e.async = true;

e.src =e.src ="https://mydomain.js;m=001;cache="+Math.random()+
"?account=0001"+
"&user_cookie=" + String(utag_data.uidCookie) +
"&session_id =" + utag_data.Session_ID);

var s =document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(e,s);

</script>
```

Finally, I would like to collect this javascript request in my Django database. Which url I need to use?
How can store this data in my dataset?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do whith the js you sent but in order to get the informations you want inside your database you have to make a request to your website, either GET or POST

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution you are looking for:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#fire-button', function(event){
        // collect all the data you want to from the webpage.
        var url = "{% url 'sample_view' %}" + "?param1=" + param1 + "&param2=" + param2 + "&param3=" + param3;
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: url,
          success: function(result){
            alert("Success");
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

views.py:

```
def sample_view(request):
    var param1 = request.GET.get('param1')
    var param2 = request.GET.get('param2')
    var param3 = request.GET.get('param3')

    models.Purchase.objects.create(
        account=param1,
        user_cookie=param2,
        session_id=param3
    )
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^sample-view$', views.sample_view, name='sample_view'),
]
```